# Set a relative path in Kivy

Tags: python, directory, kivy

Is it possible to set a relative path from the current working directory in Kivy? I'd like to set a path like

```
#:set path "../resources/file_name.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
kivy.resources.resource_add_path(path)
```

> *Add a custom path to search in.*

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.resources.html

Comment: Can I use it in #:set ?

Comment: what happens if you do ?

Comment: Kivy says "invalid value"

Comment: I ended up using the function in Python. I don't think there is a way to set a relative path in Kivy.